# Block default browser key combinations in an Angular application

Tags: angular

I am using Angular CDK listkeymanager and am able to change focus in my horizontal list component by using the left/right arrows. However, I'd like to be able to hold down CMD + left/right arrow to switch the positions of items in my list component. However, this key combination is already assigned to Chrome. Sites like Medium, Google Drive are able to block Chrome keyboard shortcuts and assign those keys for their own use. I've searched for how to do this in an Angular specific context and been unable to find any guidance. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for angular specific functionality, refer to the below repo:

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys

Hope this helps :)